# Advanced Custom Fields, Yoast SEO, not updating new values in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem: Every time I make changes to the SEO fields, the ACF fields, and Multiple content blocks on pages and try to click update, they won't save (Basically, fields that are added through customisations).

DETAILS:

- I am just starting on making a theme, based on the starkers theme Blank slate (https://github.com/viewportindustries/starkers) and haven't gone that far yet.
- I am running on Localhost via easyPHP
- This problem is mostly **Prevalent to Pages** not posts (Posts save SEO details, thankfully).
- Changes to the Body content for pages still save.
- I am suspecting it's something bad I did or something I haven't included yet on my *functions.php* file--- if there are any PHP experts here that could take a look, please, I'm begging your help.  The functions.php code is just below:
- **Workaround**: For ACF (Custom Fields) Entering Custom fields details on the generic WP custom field works (which isolates the problem on customisations on the theme).  **BUT** this does not help the problem with WP SEO.
- **Workaround**: For WP SEO, I had to change to another theme (premium theme, Batakoo) edit the SEO, and the SEO saves just fine.  Switching back to the theme I was building, the SEO fields become read-only again.
- I can't live on workarounds forever, I need fixes, so if anyone can help, please do.

THINGS THAT I'VE TRIED

Just to make sure we're on the same page and no one has to comment solutions that I've tried, here are the things I've already tried (but did not work) based on searching WP.Org for solutions to "Fields don't save on WordPress Pages":

- I've had the database tables repaired via PhpMyAdmin
- Removed extra spaces and additional comments in functions.php
- disabled all plugins except the ones I'm testing (SEO)

```
<?php
require_once( 'external/starkers-utilities.php' );
/* Theme settings */
define('WT_DIR', get_template_directory_uri());
define('WT_TEMPLATE_DIR', get_template_directory());
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
register_nav_menus(array('wt-prime-menu' => 'Main Menu'));
function wt_nav() {
wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location'=> 'wt-prime-menu','container'=> false,'menu_class'=> 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'  ));
}
/* Actions and Filters */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'starkers_script_enqueuer' );
add_filter( 'body_class', array( 'Starkers_Utilities', 'add_slug_to_body_class' ) );
/* Custom Post Types */
require_once( 'parts/cpt/cpt.php' );
/* Enqueue Scripts */

function starkers_script_enqueuer() {
wp_register_script( 'site', WT_DIR.'/js/site.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'site' );
wp_register_style( 'screen', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css', '', '', 'screen' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'screen' );
}   
function wt_scripts_and_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', WT_DIR . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'whitetower', WT_DIR . '/css/wts.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'googlefonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,400|Raleway:600,900|Montserrat:400,700' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', WT_DIR . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.2.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wtnav', WT_DIR . '/js/snav.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider', WT_DIR . '/js/flexslider.js', array(), '2.2.2', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr', WT_DIR . '/js/modernizr.js', array(), '2.7.1', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'googlefonts', WT_DIR . '/js/wt-webfonts.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wt_scripts_and_styles' );
/* Comments */
function starkers_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
?>
<?php  if ( $comment->comment_approved == '1' ): ?> 
<li>
<article id="comment-<?php  comment_ID()  ?>">
<?php  echo get_avatar( $comment ); ?>
<h4><?php  comment_author_link()  ?></h4>
<time><a href="#comment-<?php  comment_ID()  ?>" pubdate><?php  comment_date()  ?> at <?php  comment_time()  ?></a></time>
<?php  comment_text()  ?>
</article>
<?php 
endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... found it all out when I tested regular pages other than the front page. It seems to be having a problem with the way WordPress checks static page for a front page by using a "home.php".